# errors: when I write Xml file

Tags: php, xsd

1. How can I write the tag xml line to correct place ?
   `<newWord><Heb>bull</Heb><Eng>bu</Eng></newWord>`
2. **When I run the code I get the Error**."error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty" what wrong **?**
3. how can I add to tag `<newWoed>` id=1,id=2 like `<newWoed id=3>`?

   Thanks alot for helping.

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255"?>
<Favorite_Word xml:lang="EN"><newWord><Heb>bull</Heb><Eng>bu</Eng></newWord>

<newWord>
    <Heb>Cow</Heb>
    <Eng>Co</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Camel</Heb>
    <Eng>Ca</Eng>
</newWord>
<newWord>
    <Heb>Bull</Heb>
    <Eng>BUl</Eng>
</newWord>
    
</Favorite_Word>
```

the php file:

```
function addElementToXml($doc='')
{
    if(!$doc)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        // we want a nice output
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->load('Dictionary_user.xml');
    }
    $Dictionary_user = $doc->documentElement;
    #var_dump($Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->nodeName);
    $newWord = $doc->createElement('newWord');
    #$newWord->setAttribute('isbn','http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CHARSET=windows-1255"');
   
      
    $prop = $doc->createElement('Heb','bull');
    $newWord->appendChild($prop);
    $prop = $doc->createElement('Eng','bu');
    $newWord->appendChild($prop);
    
     
    $Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($newWord,$Dictionary_user->childNodes->item(0));
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo $doc->saveXML();
    $doc->save("Dictionary_user.xml");
}
    addElementToXml();
```

Comment: That XML is missing the end tag for `Favorite_Word` after the `newWord` elements.

Comment: no the are no missing tag 'Favorite_Word'.

Comment: That just seems to be a copy past issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error message:

```
DOMDocument::load(): Document is empty in Dictionary_user.xml, line: 1 in foo.php on line 10
```

It means it's either reading a wrong document. Or the document is just empty.

To add the id you only have to call setAttribute on the node you're creating.

```
$newWord = $doc->createElement('newWord');
$newWord->setAttribute('id','1');
```